# Implement RedirectFromLoginPage with two defaultUrl in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am Working on asp.net with two Login page for Staff and Student.When the Login is successful the user will be taken to WELCOME Page.But the problem is I have used RedirectFromLoginPage if the authentication is successful.Here is the code for that.

```
        protected void Buttontbl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        if (AuthenticateUser(Textusertbl1.Text,textpastbl1.Text))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Textusertbl1.Text, CheckBoxtbl1.Checked);

        }
        else
        {
           errorlbl.Text="Invalid Username or Password";
        }

       }
```

I have given the defaultUrl as WelcomeStaff.aspx so if the authentication is successful the user is redirected to that.This is the code in Web.config file

```
      <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="SelectUser.aspx" defaultUrl="welcomeStaff.aspx"/>
      </authentication>
        <authorization>
       <deny users="?"/>
     </authorization>
```

So,I need the following to be implemented,

- I want the same for another login.

  -If the authentication is successful the user must be redirected to DefaultUrl="WelcomeStudent.aspx"
- Its working fine for One Login Page.But I don't know how to implement for two aspx pages

  So,Can we have two defaultUrl for two aspx file? Is there any other way to implement?Iam new to asp.net.Plz help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually deal with that kind of situation is configure that app to return to a redirect page (ex : redirection.aspx) that will check if the user is authenticated and if so, will redirect the user to another page based on is role. ex :

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  if(User.IsInRole("Student"))
  {
    Response.Redirect("WelcomeStudent.aspx");
    return;
  }
  else if(User.IsInRole("Staff")
  {
    Response.Redirect("welcomeStaff.aspx");
    return;
  }
}

//For any other situation, return to login
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Can you tell me what is "Student" in (User.IsInRole("Student")) @mberube.Net

Comment: In asp.net, when you want to secure your application for multiple type of users, the typical way to go is to use the RoleProvider that will map your users to roles. You can then secure resources or base business logic (like in my example) on the role. If you have any other way to check if the logged user is a student or a staff member, you can put your own logic instead.